# Enable experimental features Blender 2.72

Tags: gpu

I'm using Blender 2.72 and I want to enable the experimental feature set, which supports OpenCL for my AMD/ATI graphics card (I know what the risks are of doing this). Googling it, I found a Blender Wiki page of 2.6x which said I have to change the feature set to experimental, in the render menu, right under the display options ([this is what I'm talking about](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Experimental_Features)). However, in my Blender 2.72 I don't have this option:

[image]

Could anyone help me to still get the experimental feature set to work?

Comment: It's there, but only in Cycles. Just switch your render engine to Cycles, in the info header

Comment: Ah, that's why I couldn't find it. It was indeed set to Blender Render. Thanks!

Comment: @someonewithpc I prepared an answer but you were first. Could you add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it's not appearing is because this option is only available in the Cycles render engine.

To switch to Cycles, go to the Info header (in the default layout, it's at the top) and change the engine to Cycles.

[image]